# What was the Batman TV series (1960's) episode where he explains pyramid schemes?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification, batman-1966

When I was a child, I watched the 1960's Batman TV series every chance I got. One of the episodes came to mind this morning when I was trying to explain why the [Secret Sisters](http://www.snopes.com/secret-sisters-gift-exchange/) gift exchange was a scam. Someone is trying to scam the town by proposing a pyramid scam (invest a little money now, multiple people pay you down the line as they invest) and he mathematically proved that the only people it would profit were the people who started it.

The only concrete image I have in my head is Batman (Adam West) standing in front of a room of people and using a pointer on a piece of poster board on an easel with an image of the pyramid and showing the math that every new person would need to bring in a ludicrously large number of other people in for the scheme to work.

Which episode was that?

Comment: Which series? Adam West Batman?

Comment: http://teentitansgo.wikia.com/wiki/Pyramid_Scheme

Comment: @JasonBaker: Yes. Adam West. :) I wasn't certain how exactly to indicate that, but I supposed I could always say "Adam West" or "Live Action" or "incredibly campy"

Comment: @Valorum: Sorry. It predates that one as it was the old 1966 series.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that I'm confusing another show of the era, but looking for Green Hornet episodes didn't help either.

Comment: If it was a pyramid scheme, shouldn't the villain have been King Tut?

Comment: One might think....

Comment: I'm really sorry to link here but...http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Ponzi - the only thing I see relating to DC universe is a Teen Titans Go! episode (although this site certainly isn't 100% complete)

Comment: This site appears to list all the scripts for every Batman episode from the series in question. http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=batman-1966 - I searched every script for the word "pyramid" and, as Spencer said, the only results were generally in King Tut scripts and there seemed to be no relation to pyramid or ponzi schemes (I did *not* search for other potential keywords such as ponzi, scheme, etc...) but maybe you can have better luck

Comment: I am starting to wonder if I just dreamed this... it's just so vivid in my memory.

Comment: There was a Dragnet episode where Sgt. Joe Friday did the presentation with pointer and easel in court to make the case that the defendant knew he was cheating people out of their money with a pyramid scam.  Is it possible your brain combined it with Batman?

Comment: @nATHANk: Truthfully, I could readily see my brain doing something like that. And I could see both showing up on a "vintage TV" channel.

Comment: Oh good heavens... I found the episode online and that's it. Would you like to post an answer and I can accept it and award you the bounty tomorrow?

Comment: Will close once the bounty is awarded.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it turns out the answer has nothing to do with SF&F

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There was an episode of Dragnet in which Sgt. Joe Friday gives a presentation in court using pointer and easel to make the case that the defendant knew she was scamming people out of their money using a pyramid scheme.

[image: Pyramid scheme chart]

The clincher to the argument was the observation that in order to deliver on her promises of wealth, a follower of this revival leader's group would need to induct the entire population of the United States into the scheme.

This was episode 12 of season 10, titled "The Pyramid Swindle."  It would be easy to misremember one famous deadpan lawman as another!

Comment: As indicated in the comments above, I have viewed the episode and I am convinced it is the one I'm remembering.

Comment: nice find! Well done - some of the revival episodes of Dragnet were lit in such a way that were very similar to both Star Trek and Batman of the same era: bright primary color gel spots, etc...I can understand how it might get conflated

Answer (score 5):

I think the episode you're referring to is [Batman's Waterloo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519459/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

Here is a description of the plot as given by IMDB

> Though Batman escapes his watery trap, Robin is left in the hands of King Tut. The deluded villain still believes that Lisa Carson is really Queen Cleopatra, and calls Lisa's father to demand a ransom of $8,300,487.12, the mortgage on the Pyramids. Using the Jolly Jackson radio show to communicate, Tut negotiates the terms of payment with Batman. However, the villain most likely intends to keep both the money and Lisa, and has further plans to fry the Caped Crusaders in his royal boiling oil.
>   - Written by Twenty Penguins

**EDIT**

I found another episode that kind of fits your description, but it has no mentions of Pyramids.

It's the [The Puzzles are Coming](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519548/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) episode.

> The Puzzler, a villain with a fondness for both Shakespeare and aviation, indicates he is after the fortunes of Artemus Knab. He convinces the billionaire to invest in his puzzle balloon business, but when the Dynamic Duo find that Knab seems too intelligent to fall for a phony scheme, they look deeper for the criminal's true intentions. Their search leads them to Knab's airplane monopoly, but unknown to them, the Puzzler has plans to halt their investigation - permanently.
>   - Written by Twenty Penguins

Comment: I've read through the summaries of each and there's still nothing matching what I'm looking for. There's no money scam involving the populace in either episode, and the scene I remember clearly, of Batman explaining it to the people involved and pointing out the mathematical impossibility is not there. I do appreciate your efforts.

Comment: I can think of two episodes which come close. The John Astin Riiddler episode features Bruce helping Dick with the old "cut a pie to get the most pieces" problem, and it features a bit of increasing number math.  Also I seem to recall a discussion of the "One penny, doubled daily" problem - the baddie wants that as payment, and Batman points out that it'll be millions in under a month.

Comment: @VBartilucci: Hmm... maybe I'm misremembering the latter one?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Sorry, thought these two were the ones. Unfortunately, I can't find any other episodes, or the ones that VBartilucci was mentioning :( However, I hope you can find the episode, as I know what it feels like to have an image of the episode in your head and wanting to watch it again. Good luck! :)